# Angular Cypress Component tests not working with Tailwindcss

Tags: angular, cypress, tailwind-css, cypress-component-test-runner

When running Tailwindcss in an Nx style monorepo (apps and libs folders) I have setup the Tailwind config as:

```
content: ['./apps/**/*.{html,ts}', './libs/**/*.{html,ts}'],
```

But it is not applying any Tailwindstyles and gives the error:

"warn - No utility classes were detected in your source files. If this is unexpected, double-check the `content` option in your Tailwind CSS configuration."

And no styling is applyed to the component tests.

I tried to change the content in the tailwind.config.js to:

```
content: ['/**/*.{html,ts}', '**/*.{html,ts}'],
```

Which works but makes tailwind execution slow as it will also evaluate node_modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked by adding:

```
'./src/**/*.{html,ts}'
```

To the tailwind.config.js's content:

```
content: ['./apps/**/*.{html,ts}', './libs/**/*.{html,ts}', './src/**/*.{html,ts}'],
```

Comment: I am still missing few tailwind classes here and there, maybe caused by JIT. Did you have similar issue?

Comment: No, it got solved by this.

Comment: Do you also have custom tailwind theme?

Comment: I do have a custom tailwind theme